# Is further psycopg2 SQL injection mitigtation possible?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm thinking about adding an additional layer of SQL injection mitigation in my usage of `psycopg2`

If `cursor.execute` is used properly and the parameters are passed like below this is not a concern.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = %s", (name,))
```

But I'm slightly worried about myself or another developer absentmindedly doing something like

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = %s" % (name))
```

which would of course open the door to someone submitting their name as `''; drop table employees;`

Since the second example contains a very common way of formatting a string in Python it's not outside the realm of possibility that someone could make such an error.

I'm wondering if a method similar to `execute` exists that would restrict the number of queries or statements being executed in a call to `execute` to 1. If not, does `psycopg2` expose a SQL tokenizing method. If so I could write my own method that overrides execute and performs such a check before passing the query to the real execute. Or any other suggestions appreciated.

Comment: One "second layer" is to have the query string as a separate assignment above the execution line. That should then be query strings without formatting. Not foolproof, but easier to spot.

Comment: Run [bandit](https://github.com/PyCQA/bandit) or the like on it.  Thats what it’s for.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a wrapper that forces users to name the args exactly and clobber the cursor method early with it

```py
def execute(*, call, args):
    return _execute_original(call, args)
```

I'd also be tempted to just use a linter to prevent string formatting with `%` by warning on some trivial regex like `%[^\w]` and use `.format()` or f-strings everywhere (this could be implemented anywhere convenient; CICD system, unit tests, grep in git pre-commit hook..)